# Import tensorflow issue on Python 3.6

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

When I try to import tensorflow in my Python scripts, I have some weird results. For instance:

> ```
> import tensorflow 
> from keras.datasets import imdb
> ```

gives me

> ```
> ModuleNotFoundError
> Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-12-25cf0f878919> in <module>()
>       1 import tensorflow
> ----> 2 from keras.datasets import imdb
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'
> ```

If I try:

> ```
> import tensorflow as tf
> from tf.keras.datasets import imdb
> ```

I get :

> ```
> ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-9-bd3db3d3567b> in <module>()
>       1 import tensorflow as tf
> ----> 2 from tf.keras.datasets import imdb
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tf'
> ```

But, if I use :

> from tensorflow.keras.datasets import imdb

it works.

I've been googling this for a full hour now, and I still don't understand what I'm doing wrong in the first two scripts. 
Thanks

Comment: `pip3 install keras` - tensorflow and actual Keras are different packages.

Comment: @nuric  `keras` has been part of core TF. except [`The tf.keras version in the latest TensorFlow release might not be the same as the latest keras version from PyPI.`](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras#import_tfkeras)

Comment: Thank you, I've installed the keras package and now it works as expected. But, one more question. There's a keras-gpu package. Should I use it, as I've installed CUDA 9.0 (and how to use it?) instead of keras ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't specified how and where you installed `tensorflow`, so I could be wrong, but:

(a) it appears that `keras` is installed with `tensorflow`, but not in a location that is in the default Python path (hence, you cannot do `from keras.datasets import imdb`).

(b) this combination:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tf.keras.datasets import imdb
```

is invalid, because `from x import y` searches for `x` as a module and not as a symbol in your code's globals (and `tf` is NOT a module name but a global variable, `import tensorflow as tf` imports tensorflow and sets `tf` to point to the module object).

Therefore (unless you fix your install or your PYTHONPATH to make `keras` visible as a module), you should use this to import `keras` (or specific symbols from it):

```
# either this, to access keras.*, e.g., keras.datasets.imdb
import tensorflow.keras as keras

# or this, as you've done in your example
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import imdb
```